# How to format "6.5" float as "06.5000" with leading zeros?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, formatting, export-to-csv

I want to output the float value array to a CSV-File in a data format like `06.5000`.

Is there a way in Python to trim the decimal point and to the left of the decimal point, like awk's `printf`, or matlab's `fprintf`?

Most of the Python advice I found on the net was only to control information to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```py
>>> number = 6.5
>>> f'{number:07.4f}'
# '06.5000'
```

The `0` indicates a leading zero, the `7` is the total length of the formatted number string and `.4f` is the four decimal places of your float.